# Linux Assembly - Printing unicode without printf

Tags: linux, assembly, unicode, x86, system-calls

Is there a way to print unicode characters to the Linux console without using printf?

I know printf is the 'correct' way to do it, I'd just like to know if its possible using pure x86 assembly.

Comment: There is nothing magical about `printf` or unicode. You can just use `write`, either the libc wrapper or the syscall directly. As long as you actually use the correct unicode values and your terminal (or whatever else is at the other end of the output fd) understands it.

Comment: The console is just a file. You just send characters (normal, unicode, control character) in any way you want. I suspect you are more interested in the receiving part (printing/displaying), but this is also much more complex, and it depends on the console/printer (so not much about Linux, and the console could be displayed on other OS).

Answer (score 2):

If by *using pure x86 assembly* you mean not having to include/link any 3rd-party library then yes, you can print to console with kernel service [write](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write). I don't think it is less correct than using C library. I saved the following example encoded in UTF-8 as "sample.asm", then assembled, linked and run with

```
nasm -f ELF32 sample.asm -o sample.o
ld sample.o -o sample -m elf_i386
./sample
```

and it worked as expected.

```
SEGMENT .data
Sample DB "Sample text of mixed alphabets:",10
       DB "Éireannach (Eireannach in western European alphabet)",10
       DB "Čapek (Capek in central European alphabet)",10
       DB "Ørsted (Oersted in Nordic alphabet)",10
       DB "Aukštaičių (Aukshtaiciu in Baltic alphabet)",10
       DB "Ὅμηρος (Homer in Greek alphabet)",10
       DB "Yumuşak ğ (Yumushak g in Turkish aplhabet)",10
       DB "Maðkur (Mathkur in Icelandic alphabet)",10
       DB "דגבא (ABGD in Hebrew alphabet)",10
       DB "Достоевский (Dostoevsky in Cyrillic alphabet)",10
       DB 0
SizeOfSample EQU $ - Sample
SEGMENT .text
GLOBAL _start:
_start:MOV EAX,4      ; Kernel function sys_write in 32bit mode.
       MOV EBX,1      ; File descriptor of standard output.
       MOV ECX,Sample ; Offset of the written text.
       MOV EDX,SizeOfSample ; Number of bytes (not characters).
       INT 0x80       ; Invoke kernel service.
       MOV EAX,1      ; Kernel function sys_exit in 32bit mode.
       INT 0x80       ; Invoke kernel service.
```

Here is the same example in 64bit mode:

```
SEGMENT .data
Sample DB "Sample text of mixed alphabets:",10
       DB "Éireannach (Eireannach in western European alphabet)",10
       DB "Čapek (Capek in central European alphabet)",10
       DB "Ørsted (Oersted in Nordic alphabet)",10
       DB "Aukštaičių (Aukshtaiciu in Baltic alphabet)",10
       DB "Ὅμηρος (Homer in Greek alphabet)",10
       DB "Yumuşak ğ (Yumushak g in Turkish aplhabet)",10
       DB "Maðkur (Mathkur in Icelandic alphabet)",10
       DB "דגבא (ABGD in Hebrew alphabet)",10
       DB "Достоевский (Dostoevsky in Cyrillic alphabet)",10
       DB 0
SizeOfSample EQU $ - Sample
SEGMENT .text
GLOBAL _start:
_start:MOV RAX,1        ; Kernel function sys_write in 64bit mode.
       MOV RDI,1        ; File descriptor of standard output.
       LEA RSI,[Sample] ; Offset of the written text.
       MOV RDX,SizeOfSample ; Number of bytes (not characters).
       SYSCALL          ; Invoke kernel service.
       MOV EAX,60       ; Kernel function sys_exit in 64bit mode.
       SYSCALL          ; Invoke kernel service.
```

created with

```
nasm -f ELF64 sample.asm -o sample.o
ld sample.o -o sample 
./sample
```

Comment: You're unnecessarily writing a binary `0` byte to stdout.  That's generally not a good thing, although if stdout is a terminal, most terminal emulators ignore it.  (`write` takes a `void*` and `size_t len`, not a 0-terminated C string)